I have issue with Babylon.js "warning error: logger.ts:107"
I have an issue as below. I can run the code smooth before then suddenly It show warning as below. I don’t add or fix anything i just run my code again and again. It like I run it successfull and no warning then when I reset to render again it suddenly unable do anything.
enter image description here
Please help me run it normaly again. I have no idea why this happen.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
